# How to add datazoom to a vega plot?

Tags: plot, vega

How to create a plotchart with datazoom sliders (like this one in [echarts](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/editor.html?c=area-simple)) in vega? I suppose I could bind signals to sliders, and then filter data, but it will be two sliders and no background image.

Advice?